# Anchor tags in the new DocuSign Apps Launcher

Tags: docusign

I've been using DocuSign eSignature (Legacy) and is a frequent user of Custom Tags (anchor tags). The org that I am handling decided to get the new DocuSign Apps Launcher and I've been playing around with the new app. My questions is:
-Does the new DocuSign Apps Launcher have Custom Tag (anchor tag) feature as well? I don't know if i'm just missing something but for some reason I can't find this feature in the new app.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Since it's a Docusign app, you'll have to check with Docusign support.

Answer (score 1):

It does, but you can only access it by logging in to your DocuSign account on their website (https://account.docusign.com/).

Once there: Settings > Document Custom Fields in the sidebar on the left.

I spoke to DocuSign support about this and it seems it's not available in the DAL UI, at least not yet.